# Figure Out if the Window Is In Focus

Tags: javascript

I have an uploader that takes roughly 30 seconds to upload the images, render the thumbnails, and move to another server.

Is there any way to check after (or at any time) to see if they have lost focus of the window and if they aren't in focus to send an alert. (I would know how to send the alert, just need to figure out how to check if focus is given)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would code an event for the window. For example:

```
window.onblur = function () {
// place your code here
}
```